# search nongreedily for a bunch of terms delimited by parentheses

Tags: search, replace

I have something like the following text

```
( parens ) ( 1 + growth )   (1+growth)   (1 +growth) ( parens )
```

and I'd like replace every instance of `( 1 + growth )`, regardless of whitespace,  with say, `growthFun`

The nongreedy search command

```
:g/(.\{-}1.\{-}+.\{-}growth.\{-})/s//growthFun/gc
```

almost works, i.e., it locates the second and third instances, but the first time around it grabs   `( parens ) ( 1 + growth )`

This is puzzling since it does *not* do the same thing at the end of the line, i.e., it does not grab  `(1 +growth) ( parens )` the third time around.      Could somebody please explain why the difference, and then how to avoid the first incorrect grab?

A closely related question is:    the nongreedy construction `.\{-}` must be the most horrible, unnatural things the `vi` inventors every invented.    Is there a way to alias it in `.vimrc` so that, for example, typing

:g/( ;ng 1 ;ng etc )

would expand to

:g/( .\{-}  1 .\{-}  etc )

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: If I replace `.\{-}` with `\s\{-}` or `[^()]`, the command looks like it works according to your requirement. Would that be acceptable (look just for a space(s) or non-parenthesis in lieu of non-newline characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than searching for as few of any character as possible, change it to search for as many white space characters as possible.  This can be done by replacing `.\{-}` with `\s*`.

I would simplify (at least I think it's simpler) further with this:

```
:%s/(\s*1\s*+\s*growth\s*)/growthFun/gc
```

Also, take a look at `:help character-classes`.  There are a lot of really useful character classes that can be used to match only certain types of characters, such as only digits or only lower case letters.

Edit:
It occurs to me that I didn't necessarily answer your questions.

The reason you are seeing a difference in behavior is because the end of your pattern is `growth.\{-})` and `\{-}` finds 0 or more of the previous atom, but as few as possible.  So, this is basically saying "Find `growth`, then find a `)` and do it in as few characters as you can".  Since there is a `)` immediately after the last `growth`, it doesn't have to go very far.

On the other hand, the beginning of your pattern is `(.\{-}1` which similarly says "Find a `(` and a `1` and do it in as few characters as you can".  Since a `1` doesn't appear within the first group of parentheses, it has to continue until the second group.

I'm not aware of any way to alias the `.\{-}`.  I also found this syntax rather awkward at first, but it seems to make a bit more sense when you realize that you can use numbers inside the curly braces to specify exactly how many to match (or even a range of how many to match).  For example, you can do `\{6}` to find exactly 6 of the previous atom or `\{2,6}` to find 2 to 6 of them.  Adding a `-` such as `\{-6}` means to find up to 6, but as few as possible.  Leave out the number (i.e. `\{-}`) and you're just saying "find as few as possible".  `:help pattern-multi-items` has a bunch more information about this.

Comment: Thanks to all three responses.    I accepted @Pak 's response because `\s*` is so much easier to type than `\s.\{-}` and for the explanation !

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

**Replace non-new line character with the space character or non-parenthesis**

If we examine the start of your match expression, `(.\{-}1`, we see that we can find a quick match which finds the minimum number of non-newline characters until the first `1`.

Here are the results of this match, `/(.\{-}1`:

[image: (.{-}1]

This behavior you are seeing is expected behavior.

---

I like the idea of going after a space character, `\s`, or a non-parenthesis character class for our atom which we are trying to find a non-greedy match:

```
:g/(\s\{-}1\s\{-}+\s\{-}growth\s\{-})/s//growthFun/gc
```

Here are the results:

[image]

Here is my  non-parenthesis character class command:

```
:g/([^()]\{-}1[^()]\{-}+[^()]\{-}growth[^()]\{-})/s//growthFun/gc
```

Here are the results for non-parenthesis character class:

[image]

With your second question, I personally like the syntax for quantifiers.  Perhaps someone else has some ideas on this.